# How do I find a memory leak in C

Tags: c, memory-leaks

```
Direct leak of 1990230 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
#0 0x4089b5 in malloc (/home/oem/Загрузки/assignment-image-rotation-master/build/lsan/image-transformer+0x4089b5)
#1 0x42809f in from_bmp /home/oem/Загрузки/assignment-image-rotation-master/solution/src/bmp.c:41:15
#2 0x428383 in open_bmp_from_file /home/oem/Загрузки/assignment-image-rotation-master/solution/src/bmp.c:86:31
#3 0x4284e9 in main /home/oem/Загрузки/assignment-image-rotation-master/solution/src/main.c:15:5
#4 0x7f3f9dbf50b2 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:308:16

Direct leak of 24 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
#0 0x4089b5 in malloc (/home/oem/Загрузки/assignment-image-rotation-master/build/lsan/image-transformer+0x4089b5)
#1 0x427e59 in rotate /home/oem/Загрузки/assignment-image-rotation-master/solution/src/transformation.c:8:73
#2 0x42850e in main /home/oem/Загрузки/assignment-image-rotation-master/solution/src/main.c:16:38
#3 0x7f3f9dbf50b2 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:308:16

Indirect leak of 1990230 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
#0 0x4089b5 in malloc (/home/oem/Загрузки/assignment-image-rotation-master/build/lsan/image-transformer+0x4089b5)
#1 0x427e8b in rotate /home/oem/Загрузки/assignment-image-rotation-master/solution/src/transformation.c:11:47
#2 0x42850e in main /home/oem/Загрузки/assignment-image-rotation-master/solution/src/main.c:16:38
#3 0x7f3f9dbf50b2 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-eX1tMB/glibc-2.31/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:308:16
```

Hi, I can't figure out why where is the memory leaking, as I understand it in this function? how can I fix a memory leak, maybe I'm not looking there? I kind of free my memory wherever I need it, but I have little experience to see everything.

Here is the read function:

```
enum read_status
from_bmp(FILE *in, struct transformation *img)
{
    struct bmp_header header = { 0 };

    if (!read_header(in, &header)) {
        if (feof(in))
            return READ_UNEXPECTED_EOF;
        return READ_FILE_ERROR;
    }

    img->height = header.biHeight;
    img->width = header.biWidth;
    img->data = malloc(sizeof(struct pixel) * img->height * img->width);

    size_t padding = (4 - (img->width * 3 % 4)) % 4;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < img->height; i++) {
        if (fread(&(img->data[i * img->width]), sizeof(struct pixel), img->width, in) < 1) {
            if (feof(in))
                return READ_UNEXPECTED_EOF;
            free(img->data);
            return READ_FILE_ERROR;
        }
        fseek(in, padding, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    return READ_OK;
}
```

Here is the rotate function:

```
struct transformation *
rotate(struct transformation const source)
{
    struct transformation *new_rotate_image =
        (struct transformation *) malloc(sizeof(struct transformation));

    new_rotate_image->width = source.height;
    new_rotate_image->height = source.width;
    new_rotate_image->data = (struct pixel *)
        malloc(source.height * source.width * sizeof(struct pixel));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < source.height; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < source.width; j++) {
            new_rotate_image->data[j * source.height +
                (source.height - 1 - i)] = source.data[i * source.width + j];
        }
    }

    return new_rotate_image;
}
```

Comment: Is that output from valgrind? If you compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and run your program (without valgrind), it will usually tell you the line in your code where you allocated the data that you later leaked. Add `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors` too for good measure

Comment: that LeakSanitizer

Comment: I think you need to provide a [mre].

Comment: You do not show the code freeing memory

Comment: This is the point, as I understand it, I do not release her at all? How do I do this in my code?

Comment: @HelloWorld You should call `free` just as many times as you called `malloc` - on the pointers returned by those `malloc`s

Comment: @TedLyngmo apparently I do not quite understand correctly how memory is allocated in this case

Comment: If you `malloc` inside a function and don't return the pointer to the calling function, you need to `free` the pointer inside the function. If you return the pointer to the calling function, that function needs to `free` it - or return it to a calling function, that `free`s it ... etc.

Comment: Example where it may leak: `if (feof(in)) return READ_UNEXPECTED_EOF;` You have the `free` _after_ that line. Put the `free` before it to avoid that particular leak.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: You pass the `source` transformation _by value_ to `rotate`. That looks a bit expensive since you allocate memory and then copy from `source` into the new memory and then just discard `source`. Take a pointer to `source` instead.

Comment: The error messages are really helpful to find the places where your call `malloc()`, they even give you the call stack. But it's up to you to design your software in a way that any memory allocated is freed again.